# Make a Custom Conditional Statement - Java

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Is there a way to make a custom conditional statement? Or is this not possible and I would have to just put the function inside of an `if`.

For example:

```
customConditional(bar){
    //run this code
}
```

Where if `bar` was `1` it would execute the code and any other number wouldn't.

**Edit:** What I was trying to say was, how are conditionals defined and is there a way to define another one?

Comment: Plus one, nothing wrong with the question. You can't do this in Java. (You could in C++, but you'd need to replace the curly brackets with square ones and do a lot of operator overloading trickery).

Answer (score 3):

No need to do that, all you need is a method that will return a true/false statement then use it inside an if condition:

Example:

```
private boolean myOwnMethod(int bar) {
    return bar == 1;  //this check can be as simple or complex as you need
}
```

Usage:

```
if (myOwnMethod(bar)) {
    //run this code
}
```

Comment: In this case, ``myOwnMethod`` should be declared ``public static`` in a helper ``class``. If you like to, you can add a ``static import`` statement for the helper ``class``...

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman not really, actually that will defeat OO Design.. It can be public/private/protected,  be part of the object or a helper as you state... There is not sufficient context on the question to determine the scope